# Underlying HTML Div Wrongly Showing when Zoomed (Cross Browser)

Tags: javascript, html, css, zooming

I've hit a zoom-related problem with some fairly simple HTML that appears to reproduce cross browser - in Chrome, Firefox 74, and IE11 at least.  I basically just have a hierarchy of 3 divs, with the middle div configured to draw a 1px border, and the innermost and outermost divs configured with different background colors.

```html
<html><body>

<div style="left: 0px; top: 0px; width: 320px; height: 262px; background-color: red; overflow: visible;" >
    <div style="border:1px solid grey;left: 0px; top: 0px; width: 318px; height: 260px; overflow: hidden;">
        <div style="left: 0px; top: 0px; width: 318px; height: 260px; overflow: hidden; background-color: white;">
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

The problem is that at specific (but not all) zoom ratios, the outermost div (in this sample having a red background) "bleeds" through and is visible as a red line below the innermost div (and next to the bottom border of the middle div).  I'd normally just chalk such a problem up to a browser bug - except that it's cross browser.  So the question is, am I doing something wrong?  I.e., is this HTML not valid?

Attached are screenshots (including magnified shots) in [Chrome](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rCIQh.png) [(closeup)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/97xn8.png) (125%), [Firefox](https://i.stack.imgur.com/itL6e.png) [(closeup)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aJOJt.png) (125%), and [IE11](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6NoVg.png) (425%).  Note that strangely, the red line is on opposite sides of the border in Chrome vs. Firefox. Also note that in IE11, at 425% zoom, you can see that the red line is about 1px thick, about 1/4th of the border at that zoom factor, indicating that this is perhaps a subpixel rendering issue.

If you set the width and height of the two inner divs to 100%, that gets rid of the red line, but it's not a fix as since box-sizing is by default "content-box", this actually enlarges the div by 2px along both axes.  If I apply "box-sizing:border-box" to the middle div, then the 100% sizing doesn't enlarge it relative to the original, but the red line is back.

Is there a common browser spec for rendering such HTML that perhaps can explain why this zoom problem is cross browser?  Critically, what is the suggested HTML to avoid this problem?

Comment: This is indeed a subpixel rendering issue.